# Is there an easy way to kill a 'play' job (from sox)

Tags: sound, kill, sox

I use the `play` utility from the `sox` package to generate noise so that sirens won't wake me up at ungodly hours! However `play` runs like a daemon, meaning that pressing Ctrl+C will not stop it. So I need to kill it with a `kill` command which is a little cumbersome (finding the job id or entering a password for `killall`.) Is there an 'easy' way to send a stop signal to a running instance of `play`? Possibly provided by the `sox` package itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can kill a process by its name by using `pkill`.

If the utility is named `play`, the following would work.

```
pkill play
```

Comment: How come I didn't know about this.

Comment: Yeah, it's a life saver for things that spawn mutliple pids.  I've even created an alias for my vpn software (viscocity on mac) that occasionally fails and crashes returning from sleep.  @Reza